# CVS add error for adding a new file

Tags: linux, cvs

I'm trying to use CVS on my linux machine for the first time for a project, and I keep hitting my head against the same brick wall.

I have created a projects directory as `/home/myuser/cvsproject`

I then set the environment variable for CVS as:
`export CVSROOT=/home/myuser/cvsproject`

I then ran the initialize for CVS as: `cvs init`
This created the CVSROOT folder under my projects directory.

I then created a lower level project directory, as `/home/myuser/cvsproject/project1`

I added these project details in the modules file at the end as 
`project1 project1`

I am now trying to add a new file to the repository with `cvs add project1/filename.txt` but I get the following error: 
`cvs add: in directory project1:
cvs [add aborted]: there is no version here; do 'cvs checkout' first`

The file is in my current directory, located in `/home/myuser/cvsproject/`
If I try to add the file without the project1 prefix: `cvs add filename.txt` I get the same error still.

I am able to check out a file in the CVSROOT directory, i.e. 
`cvs checkout CVSROOT/modules` so CVS is definitely working.

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CVS is not decentralised, you shouldn't make your project directory the root of CVS repository. Set `CVSROOT` to different place where your repository will reside (that is *not* the same place as your project's working directory - it should be some place new, where CVS will create its structure), then `add` or `import` everything you need (don't forget to `commit`). If you want another working copy, you should `checkout` from the same CVSROOT.